# Issue with Magento bundle products price

Tags: php, magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

i had this issue with bundle products price at saving order:

- Price at front-end [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lLKI.png)
- Price at processed order on front-end [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OolP.png)

In the backend i have price ₡ 100,000,000.00

I'm using IWD Onepage Plugin for checkout, any ideas of where can I change the order save method for this price?

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there any code you can post?  That would help us answer your question.

Comment: Hi Duston, I don't have any code, because is the save order function on Magento.